# Use android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" within the app. vpn not working

Tags: android, vpn

The apk needs system permissions. After adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system", it is found that the vpn does not work properly, and it is no problem after canceling。

After adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the app, the error is that the following code returns null。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpNaN.png)

Please tell me the reason and solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in Android11